# Require one of three text fields to be completed, validation not working on strong view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making it a requirement for at least one of three fields to be completed, if not then that should yield validation error. This is becoming rather annoying since I've done it before in jQuery and for some reason it simply will not work on this project.

Live validation is working for all other fields (which by the way I removed from the view to keep this easy to read) but when I add jQuery validation directly into the view (as you can see below) to set a requirement for at least one of three to be entered, it does nothing. No effect on the form, while all the other fields get proper validation such as email, password/confirm password matching, so on... Any ideas on what is causing this conflict??

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and a strong view; bundleling/minification is setup, I've included references to all the following:

- `jquery.unobtrusive`
- `jquery.validate 1.11.1`
- `additional-methods 1.11.0`
- `jquery-ui 1.10.4 + base theme`
- `jquery 2.1.0`
- `modernizr`

**RegistrationViewModel**

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
[StringLength(25)]
[Display(Name = "Work number: ")]
public string WorkPhone { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
[StringLength(25)]
[Display(Name = "Mobile number: ")]
public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
[StringLength(25)]
[Display(Name = "Home number: ")]
public string HomePhone { get; set; }
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test Reg</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div>
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

**View**

```
@model Web.Models.RegistrationViewModel
@{  
    ViewBag.Title = "Registration";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";   
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Form Submission
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function(obj) {
            var isValid = $("#RegistrationForm").valid();

            if (isValid) {
                obj.preventDefault();
                $('#RegistrationForm').submit();
                return false;
            }
        });

        //JQuery Validation
        $("#RegistrationForm").validate({
            rules: {

                txtWorkPhone: {
                    require_from_group: [1, ".phoneGroup"]
                },
                txtHomePhone: {
                    require_from_group: [1, ".phoneGroup"]
                },
                txtMobilePhone: {
                    require_from_group: [1, ".phoneGroup"]
                }
            }
        });

    });

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id="RegistrationForm" }))
{
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Registration failed, please verify that all fields are properly completed.");
   <div>
       <fieldset>
           <legend>Registration</legend>

           <div>
               @Html.LabelFor(p=>p.WorkPhone)
               @Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.WorkPhone, new {@class="phoneGroup", name="txtWorkPhone"}) 
           </div>
           <div>
               @Html.LabelFor(p=>p.HomePhone)
               @Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.HomePhone, new {@class="phoneGroup", name="txtHomePhone"})
           </div>
           <div>
               @Html.LabelFor(p=>p.MobilePhone)
               @Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.MobilePhone, new {@class="phoneGroup", name="txtMobilePhone"})
           </div>

           <input type="submit" value="Register" id="btnSubmit" />
      </fieldset>
   </div> 
}
```

---

**Update 1**

Tested the following code after going over posted answer, not entirely sure If I got this setup properly, doesn't seem like it since its still not working.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnSubmit').click(function (obj) {

            $("#RegistrationForm").rules("add", {
                txtWorkPhone: { require_from_group: [1, ".phoneGroup"] },
                txtHomePhone: { require_from_group: [1, ".phoneGroup"] },
                txtMobilePhone: { require_from_group: [1, ".phoneGroup"] },
                messages: {
                    txtWorkPhone: "Enter at least one phone number.",
                    txtHomePhone: "Enter at least one phone number.",
                    txtMobilePhone: "Enter at least one phone number."
                }

            }).validate();


            var isValid = $("#RegistrationForm").valid();

            if (isValid) {
                obj.preventDefault();
                $('#RegistrationForm').submit();
                return false;
            } 
        });

});
```

Comment: Add a [Required] Tag to each of the properties.

Comment: Anon, wouldn't that require all three to be filled?

Comment: Im sorry, I thought you were wanting that. Why not just check each element on submit button click and validate there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues. First, your main problem is that you haven't provide any messages to be displayed if validation fails. So, basically, even when validation fails for this, there's no indication of such.

Second, calling `.validate` causes validation to occur right then. Since the code you have  here runs on page load, the form is instantly validated with these additional rules (probably not what you intended). Then, later, when the user actually submits the form, validation is run again, but, and this part is key, *not including those rules*. Instead, it's run with the original rules that the Microsoft validation scripts added. You didn't actually update the ruleset, you just told one specific validation call to incorporate those rules.

To update the list of rules for all calls of `validate`, you need to use `.rules` instead.

See: http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules

**UPDATE**

Microsoft includes some wiring for jQuery Validation on its own, that is included in the jqueryval script bundle. This sets up the default rules and initializes validation. That means, you don't have to do that. It also ties into the submit event for the form, so you also don't need to do anything for that either.

In your scenario, all you *need* is to add some additional rules to the default validation rules that Microsoft has already set up for you. Also, the `rules` method applies to individual fields, rather than the form. This is what you need to do on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtWorkPhone").rules("add", {
        require_from_group: [1, ".phoneGroup"]
    });
    $("#txtHomePhone").rules("add", {
        require_from_group: [1, ".phoneGroup"]
    });
    $("#txtMobilePhone").rules("add", {
        require_from_group: [1, ".phoneGroup"]
    });
});
```

Comment: Chris thank you for the response, very helpful! I'm going over the link you provided but can't seem to get this working. Would you be kind to provide an example on how my current code would look with a `.rules` in-place? Check my updated post, I added what I attempted after going over your question but not too sure if its even correct. Thanks

Comment: Are you including the default jqueryval script bundle or are you handling all of this manually?

Comment: Thank you :) Its working now, I created a bounty of 100 for you, will be moving it forward in 23 Hours. Take care.

Comment: Bit weird, after adding the code in your answer the phone numbers validation works but then it wont show the validation errors for the rest of the fields when I click submit, it will show it when i move up and click on each individual field.... When I remove the code it displays the error messages for the fields not entered; put the code back and only Phone Number validations show upon submission. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Chris solution i suggest you to just write a 
**@Html.ValidationMessage("Error")** ..

Like that place the above block of code after your control creation and binding in VIEW which is stogly typed .

Regards